# Is it possible to use a trigger for a stage that isn't the first one of a Gitlab/CI pipeline?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab/ci project and am working to make it work with another jenkins project, the stages of gitlab ci are the following:

```
#gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - build
  - notifyJenkinsToStartTests
  - waitForTestsToEnd
```

build is the standard build stage triggered by a merge request on gitlab.
notifyJenkinsToStartTests starts once the build stage is over and uses a curl to trigger Jenkins to start a battery of tests.
The thing is that I would like the waitForTestsToEnd stage only to start after the tests on Jenkins are over. In order to do this I created a trigger on *settings - CI/CD*  and I configured the stage waitForTestsToEnd like this:

```
#waitForTestsToEnd
needs:
    - notifyJenkinsToStartTests
only:
    - triggers
```

(I need some artefacts from the previous stage which is why i need notifyJenkinsToStartTests)

For the notification on the jenkins side I use the suggested curl (and added the right logins):

```
curl -u login:password -X POST \
     -F token=TOKEN \
     -F ref=REF_NAME \
     https://gitlab*****/api/v4/projects/****/trigger/pipeline
```

The thing is that the waitForTestsToEnd stage doesn't even appear in the pipeline menu, so I was wondering whether it's possible to use a trigger for a job in the middle of the whole pipeline after it has started.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You could make the job in the `waitForTestsToEnd` manually triggered by adding this config:

```
when: manual
allow_failure: false
```

When you trigger the Jenkins process, include the GitLab project ID (`CI_PROJECT_ID` environment variable) and pipeline ID (`CI_PIPELINE_ID` or `CI_PIPELINE_IID`, not sure which..). When Jenkins has finished it can use the GitLab API to [list jobs in the GitLab pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs).

`GET /projects/:id/pipelines/:pipeline_id/jobs`

When you have the job ID of the manual job waiting to be triggered, you can use the GitLab API to [trigger it](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#play-a-job):

`POST /projects/:id/jobs/:job_id/play`